# Javascript code doesn't work at jsfiddle.net

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

Why doesn't it work??

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malesan/Ca4Aj/)

HTML

```
<input id="Hola" type="button" value="Hola"/>
```

Javascript

```
$('#Hola').click(function() {
alert ("Hola"); });
```

Comment: You should include jquery library in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/Ca4Aj/1/

Comment: THANKS !!! This is my first time in  jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

You'll get this error from the browser console (*you can press F12 and navaigate to console tab*):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

It's because you're missing `jQuery` core library in your demo.

So for `jsFiddle`, you can choose jQuery version from `Frameworks & Extensions` tab.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ca4Aj/2/)**

Comment: Why should this answer get 2 down-votes when it is indeed correct?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing

Comment: Trolls on the internet?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky It's a good answer to a bad question, and I think the question should be closed, so I downvoted. I mean no offense to Felix or the asker; I just hope to discourage questions like this in the future.

Comment: While I respect your opinion but I'm personally of the opinion that an answer should get votes on its own merit, there's a whole thread for that: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252003/should-i-downvote-attempted-answers-to-bad-too-broad-questions

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Thanks for the link, I have read that thread before, and I agree with the highly downvoted question at the bottom, haha. I feel like downvoting answers to bad questions is a necessary evil. I'd be less likely to downvote a new or low-rep user for answering, but maybe that makes me a hypocrite.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Jquery` and you are trying to run on pure `Javascript`

When you are refering `JQUERY` or `$` then need to provide jquery reference

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ca4Aj/3/)